# Reference request: crowded space

Tags: general-topology, reference-request

A topological space $X$ is called [dense-in-itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense-in-itself) if if has no isolated point, equivalently, if every point of $X$ is a limit point.
This is classic terminology.  [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20060131024626/http://www.aic.uni-wuppertal.de/fb7/hausdorff/Topologischer_Raum.pdf) on p. 5 mentions that this term (*insichdicht* in German) was introduced by Cantor, and Kuratowski's book further gives a reference to Cantor's article in Math. Annalen **23**(1884), p. 471.

Now it seems that *crowded space* is also used with the same meaning.  For example
[here](https://www.emis.de/journals/HOA/IJMMS/Volume2006/053653.pdf).
Does anyone know who first introduced the newer term (and why not stick with the old one)?

---

**Added:** I don't have access to https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.dmj/1077471943
(Hewitt, Edwin. *A problem of set-theoretic topology*. Duke Math. J. **10** (1943), pp. 309--333.  But many of the more recent papers that use "crowded space" make reference to it.  If anyone has access, could you check if that paper also uses "crowded space"?

Comment: One objection that I have seen to *dense-in-itself* is that ‘$X$ is dense in $X$’ does not mean the same thing as ‘$X$ is dense-in-itself’, a problem that is exacerbated when people omit the hyphens.

Comment: Motivation-a single adjective is easier to use in a sentence. Crowded seems to express the concept reasonably well, and the literal translation is awkward in English. History-no idea.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I certainly agree. It took me some time to fully get used to the distinction. Like Peter said a single adjective is easier to use.

Comment: @PatrickR: I’ve a slight preference for *dense-in-itself* simply because I’ve been using it for over 50 years and didn’t encounter *crowded* until some decades later: it’s part of my mental furniture, while I have to think for a moment when *crowded* is used.

Comment: @Peter: But *dense-in-itself* **is** a single adjective, just as *self-possessed* is a single adjective.

Comment: becoming an adjectival phrase if the hyphens are omitted, and potentially more confusing for beginners when things get inflected as in "these spaces are dense in themselves".  (But the classical term still seems more common to me.)

Comment: Cantor uses the word "insichdicht", but it seems to be an artificial compound of the three- word-phrase "in sich dicht" (= in itself dense). As Brian M. Scott comments, the reason for Cantor's creation may be that each set is dense in itself  ($\overline X = X$). However, Cantor also gives the French translation "condensé en soi" spelled in three words.

Answer (score 1):

I learnt "dicht in zichzelf" (Dutch) first, and so dense-in-itself (sometimes abbreviated to d.i.i.) seems traditional and familiar. I admit it's also possibly confusing as any $X$ is dense in $X$ so any $X$ is "dense in itself" (as a adjectival phrase, while "dense-in-itself" is a "compound adjective").

But it has history on its side (Cantor's "insichdicht" and in French "dense-en-soi" and these languages were used for topology before English was).

But personally I like the terseness of "crowded" and it's quite descriptive/intuitive as well. I'm not sure what the Dutch/German/French equivalents would be nowadays, but after L.E. J. Brouwer not many topologists wrote internationally read papers in Dutch.

Comment: @HennoBransdsma  Thanks for "dicht in zichzelf" and "dense-en-soi", but do you know when "crowded" started being used?

Comment: @PatrickR no, I only know it from some American topologists but I don’t know who came first.